# problems by scrolling a ListBox with finger touch in windows 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I developed a windows 8 app in which I present a newsarea in a ListBox control. For the news items I use a template. A news item has different sizes. The size of the item will be set after the LayoutUpdate-event. If I scroll the list by finger Tuuch, there are flicker effects. These occur because the amount of items I subsequently adapting. When I use a constant size, I have no problems with flicker effects. When I scroll the list whith the mouse there are no problemns. Is there a posibilitie to prefer this flicker effects? Do everyone had similar problems and have a solotion for me?

My template:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="components.NewsItemRenderer"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="150"
    d:DesignWidth="560" >

    <Canvas x:Name="rootCanvas"
            Width="560"
            Height="150">

        <TextBlock x:Name="lbl_title"
                   Width="480"
                   Canvas.Left="15"
                   Canvas.Top="35"
                   MaxHeight="50"
                   SizeChanged="lbl_description_SizeChanged"
                   LayoutUpdated="lbl_title_LayoutUpdated"
                   Style="{StaticResource LabelTitle}"
                   Text="{Binding Path=message.title}"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="lbl_description"
                   Canvas.Left="15"
                   Canvas.Top="55"
                   Width="480"
                   SizeChanged="lbl_description_SizeChanged" 
                   Style="{StaticResource LabelDescription}"
                   Text="{Binding Path=message.description}"/>

    </Canvas>
</UserControl>  

private void lbl_description_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            lbl_description.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, lbl_title.ActualHeight + 45);
            double _height = lbl_subject.ActualHeight + lbl_title.ActualHeight + lbl_description.ActualHeight + 40;
            this.Height = _height;
            rootCanvas.Height = _height;
        }
```

My control:

```
<ListBox x:Name="viewBox"
     Visibility="Visible"
     Background="{x:Null}"
     Foreground="{x:Null}"
     Width="580"
     Height="580"
     BorderThickness="0"
     ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource newsMessages}}"
     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource newsTemplate}"
     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource NoSelectListBoxItemStyle}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The easiest way to do this is to use the IncrementalUpdateBehavior in your XAML.

> Ref: http://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/01/15/using-incrementalupdatebehavior-to-incrementally-show-data-in-listviewbase-controls/
>
> Ref: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hanxia/archive/2013/11/04/incremental-update-item-data-for-listviewbased-controls-in-windows-8-1.aspx

This basically allows you to identify parts inside your DataTemplate that should show up first while scrolling. Cutting up your UI like this lets XAML paint much faster and reduce flicker.

Having said that, I want to also say this. Sometimes because of the quantity of data we are showing, we need to make compromises on the complexity of our data templates. That might be your case.

Best of luck!